# Is there any library in NodeJS which can search in JsonSchema at given path

Tags: node.js, json, jsonschema, jsonpath, json-schema-validator

**I have following section from JsonSchema.**

```
{
    "required":[
       "name",
       "photoUrls"
    ],
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
       "id":{
          "type":"integer",
          "format":"int64"
       },
       "category":{
          "type":"object",
          "properties":{
             "id":{
                "type":"integer",
                "format":"int64"
             },
             "name":{
                "type":"string"
             }
          },
          "xml":{
             "name":"Category"
          }
       },
       "name":{
          "type":"string",
          "example":"doggie"
       },
       "photoUrls":{
          "type":"array",
          "xml":{
             "wrapped":true
          },
          "items":{
             "type":"string",
             "xml":{
                "name":"photoUrl"
             }
          }
       },
       "tags":{
          "type":"array",
          "xml":{
             "wrapped":true
          },
          "items":{
             "type":"object",
             "properties":{
                "id":{
                   "type":"integer",
                   "format":"int64"
                },
                "name":{
                   "type":"string"
                }
             },
             "xml":{
                "name":"Tag"
             }
          }
       },
       "status":{
          "type":"string",
          "description":"pet status in the store",
          "enum":[
             "available",
             "pending",
             "sold"
          ]
       }
    },
    "xml":{
       "name":"Pet"
    },
    "$$ref":"#/components/schemas/Pet"
 }
```

I need to search whether is there any data exists at a given path like `category.id` or `tags[0].id`.

I can see [jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) module works on simple json but does not work when json schema is provided to it. I tried searching some function in swagger-client but could not found any.

So I'm looking for a library for performing this functionality. Please help me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to achieve. `jsonpath` will scan a json object and return a json structure derived from it according to the `jsonpath` rules. On the other hand, `json schema` is used to define rules for a json structure and is used to validate that a json object conforms to that structure. I can't see that you would want to apply `jsonpath` to a `json schema` unless you want to find out information about the schema itself. If that's the case your `jsonpath` must conform to the structure of the `json schema` not to the structure of the json that the schema is describing.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRC

I have a requirement to search in`Json Schema` at the given path. I know `Json Schema` is for validating the Json but the requirements are different here. I need to validate the `Json Schema` itself and I guess this can't be fulfilled by `jsonpath` module. So is there any other module that can help me to search at the given path under `json schema`?

Comment: .... And this is a part of OpenAPI schema, not `JsonSchema`. 

Sorry for making confusion here.

Comment: I would have thought that you _can_ use `jsonpath` but the syntax of the path must match the structure of the json schema. So you would have to use something like `properties.category.properties.id` to navigate to that part of the schema document. Or maybe I have completely misunderstood your objective. As an aside, if you want to _validate_ the json schema, then you could define a separate `json schema` for the schema itself,, and use that for validation.

Comment: `properties.category.properties.id` - this would just work for objects but would not work for array. 

I'll check on following.
> if you want to validate the json schema, then you could define a separate json schema for the schema itself,, and use that for validation.

Thanks @JohnRC